# How to drop memory cache periodically in Linux?

Tags: linux, caching, linux-kernel

Working on a system measurement project and it requires me to drop a cache periodically to get an accurate number (since having cache there would alter the results). Currently I can manually drop the cache by using:

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

However, I want it to automatically drop every microsecond. What command should I use?

Comment: You cannot do that (not every microsecond).

Comment: How do I at least do it periodically then? Thanks.

Comment: You could do that every 5 minutes in a `crontab` entry

Comment: @DaoLam What about using cron?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? These caches are there for a reason.

Comment: You mention `memcached` but what you drop is the filesystem cache. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin file system cache. wrong tag sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create you own command to do that, i.e. write a program to do that. For example, you could do something like:

```
while (1) {
    if ((fp = fopen("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "r")) == NULL) {
        /* error handler */
    }
    fprintf(fp, "3\n");
    fclose(fp);

    nanosleep(...); /* See nanosleep(2) */
}
```

in your program, and made it a daemon.

Comment: I'll suggest instead to `fopen` and `fclose` in the loop, and use `fputs("3",`....`)` thus avoiding the cost of  `system`

Comment: I'll do the `fopen` and the `fclose` *inside* (not before) the loop.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why? Is that a waste?

Comment: Because `/proc/` files are pseudo-files, often "computed" only once at `open` time.